# Uploading documents to google drive with curl

Tags: curl, cmd, google-api, gnuwin32

I have a spreadsheet in Google Drive and want to update it with new information everyday.

I am using cURL, sed, and awk so far. I am thinking of mixing php with it (if necessary) 
I have authenticated to my google drive and connected and can see the files within my drive but cant upload or update and new spreadsheet/

What is the best way to go about this.